# apply gradient based on 3d vector in css

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

I have this javascript (and the markup and css is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/nbed7/1/))

```
$('input[type=range]').change(function (e) {
    $('.box').css('transform','rotateY('+($(this).val()/100)*360+'deg) rotateX(20deg)');
});
```

So basically I am trying to light the cube based on some directional light coming from certain direction.

Lets say directional light is coming from (x,y,z)... (100,100,100) to (0,0,0).

Then the gradient need to be darker based on its vector alignment from on side and lighter or same depending on the other side. It's all doable but I can't wrap my mind around it as to get transformation data comes in 3dmatrix which is beyond me.

```
/* .front {    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, rgba(220,30,30,0));} */
```

pseudo code may look like this:

- get div's base color.
- get cube 3d vector based on its transformation and its parent if any.
- calculate what angle of gradient should be.
- calculate what intensity of base color should be on each side..better yet add second div inside and apply transparent gradient over it which will enable for even pictures and stuff easily.
- apply that
- etc

Comment: You may want to check this demo out for some ideas: http://peterolson.github.io/jqCube/jqCube.html

Comment: i give up lol...after thinking about next step:shadows would be too hard. I think it's doable but canvas is much better option. For shadows, i had div with borders to form triangles that are calculated using size+xy+light direction+presence of another div. Whole lot of math.

Comment: the demo i gave you - you should check out the source code and see how is he manipulating the shadow values (using hsl instead of rgb). Otherwise this question should be closed as too broad, but the topic itself may have quite some usefull info potentional for future reference, if anyone finds enough time to write down a more detailed explanation.

Comment: yes i agree...but in meanwhile the 3d game engine i was hoping to make is a no go. 
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/CxFRC/25/show (use arrow keys and mouse)

Comment: If you want 3d use real 3d - take a look into webGL and maybe something like ThreeJS